# Problem building app in React Native with expo in Run Gradlew phase

Tags: android, gradle, build, expo, eas

I'm having trouble starting my React Native app build with Expo.
This issue is occurring in the Run Gradlew phase, returning the following errors:

```
w: Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build/kotlin/sessions
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
Execution optimizations have been disabled for 7 invalid unit(s) of work during this build to ensure correctness.
Please consult deprecation warnings for more details.
536 actionable tasks: 536 executed
[stderr] FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
[stderr] 1: Task failed with an exception.
[stderr] -----------
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] Execution failed for task ':app:collectReleaseDependencies'.
[stderr] > java.io.FileNotFoundException: / (Is a directory)
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[stderr] > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[stderr] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] ==============================================================================
[stderr] 2: Task failed with an exception.
[stderr] -----------
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[stderr] > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[stderr] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] ==============================================================================
[stderr] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[stderr] BUILD FAILED in 7m 44s
```

**Here is my package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "app-name",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/spartan": "^0.2.2",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.3.5",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",
    "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.4",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.4",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "expo": "~46.0.19",
    "expo-document-picker": "~10.3.0",
    "expo-file-system": "~14.1.0",
    "expo-font": "~10.2.0",
    "expo-navigation-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.16.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.14.7",
    "firebase": "9.8.3",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.6",
    "react-native-bouncy-checkbox": "^2.1.10",
    "react-native-bouncy-checkbox-group": "^0.1.0",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-dropdown-select-list": "^1.0.18",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.5.0",
    "react-native-maps": "^1.3.2",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.9.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.18.2",
    "react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.6.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.3.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.70.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

**My eas.json:**

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.6.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleDebug"
      },
      "ios": {
        "buildConfiguration": "Debug",
        "resourceClass": "m1-medium"
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m1-medium"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m1-medium"
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

**My app.json:**

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "App Name",
    "slug": "appname",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#FF6B0F"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/images/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#fff"
      },
      "permissions": [
        "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
      ],
      "package": "com.euquero.app"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "packagerOpts": {
      "config": "metro.config.js",
      "sourceExts": [
        "js",
        "svg"
      ]
    },
    "description": "",
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "24bced36-2rfs-4d11-89e2-19013e1f178f"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried using the expo upgrade to update everything, I've used the react native upgrade helper to update correctly. I've already tried clearing Gradlew's cache (./gradlew clean).
I already updated the build.gradlew.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve it, deleted the Android folder and Ios, also deleted the Node Modules, used the 'yarn' command, used the 'eas build:configure' command, then 'npx expo prebuild' and finally 'eas build --clear- cache'.